# Definite integral with trigonometric function

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

I have some problem when trying to solve $$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1 + 3\sin^2x}dx
$$

I know, that it is the same (because it is symetric) a
$$
2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1 + 3\sin^2x}dx
$$
but it is not so much helpful...

Can you, please, help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to recognize that $\sin^2x = \frac12 (1-\cos 2x)$.  Then, the integral $I$ is

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_o^{\pi} \frac{dx}{1+3\sin^2x}\\\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{5-3\cos 2x}\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{5-3\cos x}\\\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{5-3\cos x}
\end{align}$$

Now make the substitution $u=\tan(x/2)$ so $du=\frac12 \sec^2(x/2)dx$, $\cos x=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$, and the limits of integration on $u$ go from $0$ to $\infty$.  We then can see that

$$\begin{align}
I&=2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{5-3\cos x}\\\\
&=2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{du}{1+4u^2} \\\\
&=\left(\arctan(2u)\right)\;|_0^{\infty}\\\\
&=\pi /2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply through by $\sec^2 x$

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1 + 3\sin^2 x}\,dx = \int_0^\pi \frac{\sec^2 x}{\sec^2 x + 3\tan^2 x}\,dx = \int_0^\pi \frac{\sec^2 x}{4\tan^2 x + 1}\,dx $$

Now substitute $t = \tan x$

Comment: Why there is everytime some trick with $\sec$ or $\csc$? We don't use this much in Europe :(

Comment: We don't use it where I'm from either, but you can put it in your answer as $\frac{1}{\cos x}$. In general $\sec$ and $\tan$ identities are pretty useful

Comment: @Dylan What do you propose the limits on $t$ are?

Comment: Since $\tan x$ is discontinuous at $\pi/2$, the integral is broken up
$$\int_0^{\pi}dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} dx = \int_0^{\infty} dt + \int_{-\infty}^0 dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt $$

Comment: Might have been easier to substitute $\cot x$ instead, but $\tan x$ and $\sec x$ are more familiar to people